# MvvmCross Binding a decimal to a text field on an MvxDialogFragment

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a MvxDialogFragment that I use to pop up a dialog and ask for a numeric entry with a decimal place.  If I simply bind to the Text event, then every time a type a number it formats the number and the next number comes up in the wrong spot. i.e.

You want to type in 10.00

You type the 1

1.00 shows up in the field.

you type the 0

01.00 shows up in the field.

For this reason, I created a binding called FocusText that Stuart wrote for me years ago.

```
public class MvxEditTextFocusBinding : MvxConvertingTargetBinding 
{
    protected EditText EditText
    {
        get { return (EditText)Target; }
    }

    private bool _subscribed;

    public MvxEditTextFocusBinding(EditText view)
        : base(view)
    {
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var editText = EditText;
        if (editText == null)
            return;

        value = value ?? string.Empty;
        editText.Text = value.ToString();
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.TwoWay; }
    }

    public override void SubscribeToEvents()
    {
        var editText = EditText;
        if (editText == null)
            return;

        editText.FocusChange += HandleFocusChange;
        _subscribed = true;
    }

    private void HandleFocusChange(object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var editText = EditText;
        if (editText == null)
            return;

        if (!e.HasFocus)
            FireValueChanged(editText.Text);
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(string); }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            var editText = EditText;
            if (editText != null && _subscribed)
            {
                editText.FocusChange -= HandleFocusChange;
                _subscribed = false;
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }
}
```

My AXML for the field is as follows:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/TableEditText"
    android:inputType="number"
    local:MvxBind="FocusText Amount, Converter=DecimalToStringConverter, ConverterParameter=2"
    android:id="@+id/txtAmount" />
```

My Converter is as follows:

```
public class DecimalToStringConverter : IMvxValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        if ((value != null) && (value.GetType() == typeof(decimal)))
        {
            decimal tmp = (decimal)value;
            int Decimals;
            if (parameter != null && int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out Decimals))
            {
                string format = "f" + Decimals.ToString();
                return tmp.ToString(format);
            }
            else
                return tmp.ToString();
        }
        return "";
    }

    // ConvertBack is not implemented for a OneWay binding.
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        decimal tmp;
        if (decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out tmp))
            return tmp;
        return null;
    }
}
```

This makes the EditText wait until it loses focus before setting the value.  On regular activities, I have a hidden field to which I set focus when the back button is pressed to make sure the binding flush the value to the field.  In a MvxDialogFragment, there is not a back pressed event.  By the time OnPause or OnDismiss fires, the view has already been disposed of so I can't set the focus and flush the value to the field.  Is there a better way to do this?  Is there an event that I can count on in the View or ViewModel that will happen when the dialog is closing but before the View gets disposed?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you change your EditText xml to specify "numberDecimal" as the inputType; which would allow you to bind directly to a decimal property in your viewModel. You would then not need a string to decimal converter.

I have not been able to replicate the next number coming in the wrong spot with my implementation, which can be viewed [here](https://github.com/asterixorobelix/asterixorobelix.mvx/tree/master/StackOverflow/w.dialogfrag)

Comment: Can you bind directly to a numeric property without a converter?  I thought that is what converters are for.

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the github link above, I bind directly to the numeric property. You only need to write custom converters if you are doing something which is custom and not handled by mvvmcross as a default

Comment: I can see that binding directly to a numeric property works.  The problem is that if you say type in a number and backspace it back out, when the field is empty, it does not set the value to 0.  Do you know a way to handle this?